# How do I get this vector of objects to render in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glsl, glfw

**My scene:** (the video is blurry because I had to convert this to a GIF)
There are two *other* objects that should be rendered here!

[image]

I am writing a program with GLFW/OpenGL. Essentially what I am trying to do is to be able to render a bunch of independent objects, who all can move freely around. To do this, I create a shader, a VAO, a VBO, and a EBO for each model that I want to render. static_models is a vector of class Model, and class Model is just a way to organize my vertices, indices, colors, and normals.
First is **creating the vector of Models:** (I know this class works as it should, because I use the exact same class for different shaders and buffer objects and things render well)

```cpp
    std::vector<Model> static_models;   // scale            // color
    Model plane("models/plane.ply", { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f });
    Model tetrahedron("models/tetrahedron.ply", { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }, { 0.2f, 1.0f, 1.0f });
    static_models.emplace_back(plane);
    static_models.emplace_back(tetrahedron);
```

The code for **generating the shader objects, VAOS, VBOS, and EBOS**:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < static_models.size(); i++)
    {
        Shader tempShader("plane.vert", "plane.frag");
        // create a shader program for each model (in case we need to rotate them or transform them in some way they will be independent)
        static_model_shaders.emplace_back(tempShader);

        VAOS_static.emplace_back();
        VAOS_static.back().Bind();
        VBO tempVBO(&static_models.at(i).vertices.front(), static_models.at(i).vertices.size() * sizeof(GLfloat));
        EBO tempEBO(&static_models.at(i).indices.front(), static_models.at(i).indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint));

        VAOS_static.back().LinkAttrib(tempVBO, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, 11 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        VAOS_static.back().LinkAttrib(tempVBO, 1, 3, GL_FLOAT, 11 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        VAOS_static.back().LinkAttrib(tempVBO, 2, 2, GL_FLOAT, 11 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));
        VAOS_static.back().LinkAttrib(tempVBO, 3, 3, GL_FLOAT, 11 * sizeof(float), (void*)(8 * sizeof(float)));

        VAOS_static.back().Unbind();
        tempVBO.Unbind();
        tempEBO.Unbind();
    }
```

Then the code to **create the positions and mat4 matrixes for each model**:

```cpp
// static model vectors for position and matrix
    std::vector<glm::vec3> staticModelPositions;
    std::vector<glm::mat4> staticModels;

    // initialize all static_model object positions
    for (int i = 0; i < static_models.size(); i++)
    {
        staticModelPositions.emplace_back();
        staticModelPositions.back() = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        staticModels.emplace_back();
        staticModels.back() = glm::translate(staticModels.back(), staticModelPositions.back());
    }
```

Then I **set some initial values for the uniforms**:

```cpp
std::vector<Texture> textures;

    //static objects
    for (int i = 0; i < static_models.size(); i++)
    {
        //activate first before setting uniforms
        static_model_shaders.at(i).Activate();
                                                                            // static model load model, then load lightColor, then load lightPos for each static_model
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(static_model_shaders.at(i).ID, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(staticModels.at(i)));
        glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(static_model_shaders.at(i).ID, "lightColor"), lightColor.x, lightColor.y, lightColor.z, 1.0f);
        glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(static_model_shaders.at(i).ID, "lightPos"), lightPos.x, lightPos.y, lightPos.z);

        //create texture objects
        textures.emplace_back(Texture("brick.png", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE));
        textures.back().texUnit(static_model_shaders.at(i), "tex0", 0);
    }
```

Then **drawing the models** in the game loop: (game loop not shown this is a big program)

```cpp
//draw all static models (each with a different shader and matrix)
        for (int i = 0; i < static_model_shaders.size(); i++)
        {
                                                                                //activate shader for current model
            // Tells OpenGL which Shader Program we want to use
            static_model_shaders.at(i).Activate();
            // Exports the camera Position to the Fragment Shader for specular lighting

            glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(static_model_shaders.at(i).ID, "camPos"), camera.Position.x, camera.Position.y, camera.Position.z);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(static_model_shaders.at(i).ID, "model"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(staticModels.at(i)));
            glUniform4f(glGetUniformLocation(static_model_shaders.at(i).ID, "lightColor"), lightColor.x, lightColor.y, lightColor.z, 1.0f);
            // Export the camMatrix to the Vertex Shader of the pyramid
            camera.Matrix(static_model_shaders.at(i), "camMatrix");
            // Binds texture so that is appears in rendering
            textures.at(i).Bind();

            VAOS_static.at(i).Bind();
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, static_models.at(i).indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
            VAOS_static.at(i).Unbind();
        }
```

My **vertex shader**:

```
#version 330 core

// Positions/Coordinates
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
// Colors
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
// Texture Coordinates
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTex;
// Normals (not necessarily normalized)
layout (location = 3) in vec3 aNormal;


// Outputs the color for the Fragment Shader
out vec3 color;
// Outputs the texture coordinates to the Fragment Shader
out vec2 texCoord;
// Outputs the normal for the Fragment Shader
out vec3 Normal;
// Outputs the current position for the Fragment Shader
out vec3 crntPos;

// Imports the camera matrix from the main function
uniform mat4 camMatrix;
// Imports the model matrix from the main function
uniform mat4 model;


void main()
{
    // calculates current position
    crntPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f));
    // Outputs the positions/coordinates of all vertices
    gl_Position = camMatrix * vec4(crntPos, 1.0);

    // Assigns the colors from the Vertex Data to "color"
    color = aColor;
    // Assigns the texture coordinates from the Vertex Data to "texCoord"
    texCoord = aTex;
    // Assigns the normal from the Vertex Data to "Normal"
    Normal = aNormal;
}
```

And **fragment shader**:

```
#version 330 core

// Outputs colors in RGBA
out vec4 FragColor;


// Imports the color from the Vertex Shader
in vec3 color;
// Imports the texture coordinates from the Vertex Shader
in vec2 texCoord;
// Imports the normal from the Vertex Shader
in vec3 Normal;
// Imports the current position from the Vertex Shader
in vec3 crntPos;

// Gets the Texture Unit from the main function
uniform sampler2D tex0;
// Gets the color of the light from the main function
uniform vec4 lightColor;
// Gets the position of the light from the main function
uniform vec3 lightPos;
// Gets the position of the camera from the main function
uniform vec3 camPos;

void main()
{
    // ambient lighting
    float ambient = 0.40f;

    // diffuse lighting
    vec3 normal = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightPos - crntPos);
    float diffuse = max(dot(normal, lightDirection), 0.0f);

    // specular lighting
    float specularLight = 0.50f;
    vec3 viewDirection = normalize(camPos - crntPos);
    vec3 reflectionDirection = reflect(-lightDirection, normal);
    float specAmount = pow(max(dot(viewDirection, reflectionDirection), 0.0f), 8);
    float specular = specAmount * specularLight;

    // outputs final color
    FragColor = texture(tex0, texCoord) * lightColor * (diffuse + ambient + specular);
}
```

I have other objects in the scene, and they render and update well. There are no errors in the code and everything runs fine, the objects in static_models are just not being rendered. Anyone have any ideas as to why it wouldn't be showing anything?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this after a very long time spent. The issue was this block of code:

```cpp
// static model vectors for position and matrix
    std::vector<glm::vec3> staticModelPositions;
    std::vector<glm::mat4> staticModels;

    // initialize all static_model object positions
    for (int i = 0; i < static_models.size(); i++)
    {
        staticModelPositions.emplace_back();
        staticModelPositions.back() = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        staticModels.emplace_back();
        staticModels.back() = glm::translate(staticModels.back(), staticModelPositions.back());
    }
```

There is a line missing here. After doing `staticModels.emplace_back();` we must create the identity matrix for the model. This code allows the program to function as intended:

```cpp
// static model vectors for position and matrix
    std::vector<glm::vec3> staticModelPositions;
    std::vector<glm::mat4> staticModels;

// initialize all static_model object positions
    for (int i = 0; i < static_models.size(); i++)
    {
        staticModelPositions.emplace_back();
        staticModelPositions.back() = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        staticModels.emplace_back();
        staticModels.at(i) = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        staticModels.back() = glm::translate(staticModels.back(), staticModelPositions.back());
    }
```